# Input Type = File, FileUpload disappears after JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file-upload

In an MVC application, I'm having users upload a file and then doing some error handling. This portion works fine.

The file input is:

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="browsebutton">
                <label class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    Browse<input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" class="" />
                </label></div>
```

I want to display the file name as soon as a user chooses it, so I added this bit of JavaScript and an `onChange="getFileName()`:

```
        function getFileName() {
            str = document.getElementById("FileUpload").value;
            var filename = str.substring(12, str.length);

            document.getElementById("browsebutton").innerHTML += filename;
        }
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;
```

This properly displays the filename. However, as soon as I add this, the FileUpload becomes null in my controller.

How is this JavaScript interfering with my file upload?

Comment: Is that the entirety of the `getFileName` handler?  I don't see how it could interfere with anything.

Comment: Interestingly, if I create a separate div and inject the file name into that instead of appending to the same div as button, it works fine. Which is a workable solution for me! :)

Comment: Oh, I see it now.  You're appending to the `innerHtml`, which reassigns the entire contents back to the div, resulting in a cleared input element.  You can instead create a new element and append that element to `browsebutton` using DOM methods, instead of appending a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
document.getElementById("browsebutton").innerHTML += filename;
```

With:

```
var fnSpan = document.createElement("span");
fnSpan.innerText = filename;
document.getElementById("browsebutton").appendChild(fnSpan);
```

The way you're doing it, you're setting the contents of the `innerHtml`, which ends up clearing the input (the input's value isn't part of the `innerHtml` string).  Use DOM manipulation methods instead.

You can also make the span a permanent part of the DOM, and simply set its `innerText` in your code.